# DateTime TryParse - mapping '99' to 2099, not 1999

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DateTime.TryParse century control C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760544/datetime-tryparse-century-control-c)

I need to TryParse a string such as the following: "01/01/99" into a DateTime object, and I'm using something like this:

```
DateTime outDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("01/01/99", "dd/MM/yy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out outDate))
{
     //Do stuff here
}
```

Of course, this date gets parsed as 01/01/1999, which is not what I want - I want it to parse as 2099. Is there an easy way to do this? Sadly modifying the data I'm parsing to include the full year is not an option.

Comment: Did we learn nothing from Y2K? :(

Comment: IIRC, there's a year threshold for determining century based on 2-digit year. I'm not sure whether or not the threshold can be changed via configuration.

Comment: should double digit years always be inferred to be `20yy`?

Comment: Crudely you could do "if outdate.year<2000 outdate.addyears(100)" but I supect if you did that then a kitten would die. :)

Comment: Chris, that my friend sounds perfect - sorry about the kittens!

Comment: @Chris: the method in the question this is tagged as a duplicate of is much better and allows you to much more easily set where your 100 year boundary is. I have to admit that I am struggling to find some actual concrete reasons to do that rather than just what I suggested though.

Comment: The cutoff seems 30, that is 30 = 1930 and 29 = 2029.  So, you could write some additional logic on that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760544/datetime-tryparse-century-control-c/3514865#3514865), you can supply `ParseExact()` with a culture object. Suspect `TryParseExact()` would be the same:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID);
ci.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2099;
//Parse the date using our custom culture.
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "MMM-yy", ci);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a regional setting. In Windows 7 you can edit in Control Panel > Clock, Language and Region > Region and Language. On the formats tab, hit the Advanced button and look under date.

Off the top off my head, I don't know of any way to pragmatically change this, but if you set it in control panel your app will then use it so long as you don't change the culture.

That said, you really need to go beat whoever is supplying you with this data with a heavy object. We should have eliminated this type of Y2K nonsense 12 years ago.

edit - dan04's comment link also has some options.