# Parsing 2-digit dates

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to read in a type of file with very old formatting.

In it the date format is specified at being in a yymmdd format, where a 2-digit year in the range [00, 59] is considered to be in the 21st century and a year in the range [60, 99] is considered to be in the 20th century such that 59 represents the year 2059 and 60 represents the year 1960.

How would I go about parsing this into a `DateTime` in C#?

I've tried doing:

```
string str = ReadDateFromFile();
DateTime dt;    
DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

But the default 2-digit year rules treat values in the range [00, 29] as 21st century and values in the range [30, 99] as 20th century.

Is there a way to modify this behaviour to do what I want or is there a different technique I could use?

Comment: Add a line after `TryParseExact` to subtract 100 years if it's between 2030 and 2059?

Comment: You could change the string from a 2-digit year to a 4-digit year using whatever rules you decide before you pass it to `TryParseExact`

Comment: Consider constructing your own `Calendar` class using the default as a template, and modifying the [Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: This thread looks similar and uses a culture object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208103/datetime-tryparse-mapping-99-to-2099-not-1999

Comment: @Nikki9696 Ah, I tried searching but didn't come across that.  Imust have been using the wrong words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to parse values for the date and then construct it using your custom logic:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<year>\d{2})(?<month>\d{2})(?<day>\d{2})");
var match = regex.Match(str);
var year = int.Parse(match.Groups["year"].Value);
// Same for day and month
var date = new DateTime(
    year >= 60 ? 1900 + year : 2000 + year,
    month, day);
return date;
```

Answer (score 7):

Just append the century prefix to your string and then change the format string to parse the four digit year

```
string str = ReadDateFromFile();
if (int.Parse(str.Substring(0, 2) >= 60)
   str = "19" + str;
else
   str = "20" + str;

DateTime dt;    
DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

You can modify [Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax(v=vs.110).aspx) and use the modified culture for parsing

```
var myCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
myCulture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2059;
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "yyMMdd", myCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Comment: Or cleaner `str  =  str.Substring(0, 2) >= 60 ? "19" + str : "20" + str;`

Comment: @bto.rdz Is that really cleaner? Hard to tell what it is doing at quick glance.

Comment: @bto.rdz, You are comparing string with int.

Answer (score 3):

I think that in this case, it would be easier to use a regular expression such as `(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})` to extract the year, month and day respectively, then, you do your business logic and construct a new date time object from there.

If this is a common behaviour in your application, you might want to consider making it an extension method.