# Creating a valid date from a MM/dd/yy format

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DateTime.TryParse century control C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760544/datetime-tryparse-century-control-c-sharp)

I have a C# app that's importing data from a .DBF file, and inserts it into SQL Server. There's a DOB column in the file with the dreaded `MM/dd/yy` format.  I just use the Convert.ToDateTime, and most data converts to the 1900's like I expected it to.  There are a handful of records that don't convert correctly and have people born 30 years from now.  How do I force the conversion to only write `MM/dd/19XX`?

So for example this date in the .DBF file `12/29/29` gets converted to `12/29/2029`.

I'm reading the .DBF file like so:

```
 var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(dbfPath);
            string dsPath = fileInfo.DirectoryName.ToString();

            DataSet DSResult = new DataSet();
            using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(
          @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
          @"Data Source=" + dsPath + ";" +  //Set the Data Sourde = to the directory of the file.  
          @"Extended Properties=dBASE III;"))

            using (OleDbCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cn.Open();
                cm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM UPDATED"; //Specify the file name for the select statement.  
                using (OleDbDataAdapter dba = new OleDbDataAdapter(cm))
                {


                    dba.Fill(DSResult);

                }
            }


            return DSResult;
```

Comment: Could you post an example of a record that isn't converting correctly?

Comment: how are you reading the dbf? Cos ADO should be able to read it into an DataSet

Comment: You are probably seeing data windowing (years prior to 1950 are treated as 2050).

Comment: Regardless of your solution, you'll be left with the problem of being unable to distinguish between 3-year-olds and 103-year-olds.

Comment: @Jester unless the column is a text column :(

Comment: I don't understand the windowing problem.  There are plenty of the dates in the 1940's that got converted correctly....

Comment: broke, the window is obviously set to assume that all two-digit years fall between 1930 and 2029 (or perhaps the window is 1940-2039).  @EricJ. assumed that the window was set differently, but the nature of the problem is the same, regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the [Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax.aspx) property to change the last year of the 100 year range.

```
DateTimeFormatInfo formatProvider = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
formatProvider.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = DateTime.Now.Year;

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("12/12/22", "MM/dd/yy", formatProvider);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact format  of the retrived date then You can use ParseExact() or TryParseExact() method of DateTime struct to properly convert the date representation.

It takes an additional foramt string parameter to parse exactly the way you want.

```
dateString = "Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00"; // your date string
format = "MM/dd/yy"; // format string
try {
    result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
}
```

But data windowing as mentioned in comments can be a problem

Comment: Date windowing is not *a* problem, it is *the* problem, and this solution does not address it.