# Inconsistent DateTime.Parse behavour behaviour

Tags: c#, datetime

i have small issue with Convert.ToDateTime behaviour:

```
        DateTime dt = System.Convert.ToDateTime("25JAN27");
        String dateStr = dt.ToString();
        //output: 25/01/2027 00:00:00

        DateTime dt2 = System.Convert.ToDateTime("20SEP33");
        String dateStr2 = dt2.ToString();
        //output: 20/09/1933 00:00:00
```

why 27 turns into 2027 and 33 turns into 1933 ?

thanks

Comment: Have we learned nothing from the Y2K bug? Years should be represented in 4 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the accepted answer in this post: [DateTime.TryParse century control C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760544/datetime-tryparse-century-control-c-sharp)

This behaviour is based on the TwoDigitYearMax property of the Calendar property of the CultureInfo object that you are using.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax
```