# How to convert "MM/dd/yy" string to a date with the nearest future year?

Tags: c#, .net-5, datetimeoffset

I have the date coming in as a string with the format of `MM/dd/yy`.

I'm trying to convert it to `DateTimeOffset` the following way:

```
string dateString = "02/11/48";

DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(
    dateString,
    "MM/dd/yy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out DateTimeOffset date);
```

However, when this string gets converted to `DateTimeOffset`, the year is set to 1948. Due to business logic, I know that the date in there always has the nearest future year, so the year should be 2048.

Is there a way to convert the string to `DateTimeOffset` in such a way or will I have to add additional logic on top of it after it's parsed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime.TryParse century control C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760544/datetime-tryparse-century-control-c-sharp)

Comment: So, if someone enters yesterday's date, you want to project that out 100 years?

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes, exactly, because it's not yesterday's date actually, it's the closest value of that date in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this simpler approach:

```
string dateString = "02/11/48";

DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(
    dateString,
    "MM/dd/yy",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out DateTimeOffset date);

if (date < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
{
    date = date.AddYears(100);
}
```

It simply adds 100 years if the parsed value is before now.

Comment: There is just this one small problem with February 29th.  In 99.5% of cases, two years a century apart will either both be leap years or neither will be.  But for example 2000 was a leap year and 2100 will not be.

Comment: That is actually correct, didn't think of that.

Comment: Because we are so early in the 400 year cycle, it will be almost 279 years before there's a problem.  (Specifically -- on 1st March 2300, the valid string "02/29/00" meaning 29th February 2400, a date which does exist, will fail parsing instead of returning 29th February 2300, since that date doesn't exist)  Welcome to Y2K3 bugs.

Comment: Thanks, I think that someone else will have to handle that problem at that time :)

Comment: It's safer and more efficient to use `TwoDigitYearMax`, as per the duplicate answers.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint: That won't work, since he always wants a date in the future, the `TwoDigitYearMax` wont work for dates this year.

Comment: Got it.  I missed that part.  Indeed, if really it needs to be tied to "now", then your solution is better.  I do think the OP will need to think a bit harder about time zones though.  `UtcNow` might be the appropriate basis, or it may be that they wanted the date to be interpreted in local time, or in some particular time zone.