# Conversion of DOB from mmddyy to mmddyyyy

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am facing issue while trying to convert the DOB for certain range of years, the conversion logic that I am using is,

```
DateTime.ParseExact("211290", "mmddyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).ToString("mmddyyyy")
```

If the DOB that is 211290 I am getting the correct result as 12211990.
In the same way if I change the DOB to 071429 getting the result as 07142029.

Can anybody let me know if I am making any mistake at the time of conversation. Please let me know, as this is a Production issue we are in a critical stage.

Thanks & Regards

Harsha

Comment: You're trying to parse Months as Minutes, that's why this: `211290` can be parsed by `mmddyy`. About this: `071429`, it's in the same decade as the current date (in the future). It's guessing what the year could be. In the past, if it's in the same century.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760544/datetime-tryparse-century-control-c/3514865#3514865

Comment: If this data is coming from a database as a string you should look at storing it as a Date in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

First of all format string patterns are case sensitive/camelCase, that means `mmddyy` is not `MMddyy` as `mm` represent minutes and `MM` months.
Secondly assuming you are trying to transform just a date input (with not a time) you can use `Date.ParseExact` rather `Datetime.ParseExact` *(but ok that remains optionally)* and more important in that is that `211290` will never be a MONTH/DAY/YEAR(2 places) as a 21°-th Month doens’t exist.
For more info you can see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0

```
'WRONG INPUT    
'WRONG INPUT NEEDS THAT you have to change MMddyy in ddMMyy or 211290 in 122190:
'Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("211290", "MMddyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).ToString("MMddyyyy"))

'As follows
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("211290", "ddMMyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).ToString("MMddyyyy"))
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("122190", "MMddyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo).ToString("MMddyyyy"))
```

Comment: `var dtInfo = (DateTimeFormatInfo)DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone(); dtInfo.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = DateTime.Today.Year; var res = DateTime.ParseExact("122128", "MMddyy", dtInfo);`. Now `122128` is parsed as `december 21 1928` instead of `december 21 2028`

Comment: Yes, You can add this as an answer/suggestion related to the `TwoDigitYearMax` about two digits before last two.