# Convert a two digit year to a four digit year

Tags: c#, string, date

This is a question of best practices. I have a utility that takes in a two digit year as a string and I need to convert it to a four digit year as a string. right now I do

```
//DOB's format is "MMM (D)D YY" that first digit of the day is not there for numbers 1-9
string tmpYear = rowIn.DOB.Substring(rowIn.DOB.Length - 3, 2); //-3 because it is 0 indexed
if (Convert.ToInt16(tmpYear) > 50)
    tmpYear = String.Format("19{0}", tmpYear);
else
    tmpYear = String.Format("20{0}", tmpYear);
```

I am sure I am doing it horribly wrong, any pointers?

Comment: I think you should randomly choose between 19-- and 20--. Didn't anyone learn from Y2K not to use 2 digit years?

Comment: Some customers <strike>have their heads so far up their asses</strike>mandate use of 2-digit years.

Comment: Is there any other date info in the db to help?  Age?  Last visit to the vet?  Latest image?  IsAlive?  DODeath?  Hopefully you can push to have the db updated.

Comment: @JoePhillips Some developers weren't even born during Y2K...

Comment: @Garath I'm sure it's a lesson taught in schools to the younger generations at this point

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The .NET framework has a method that does exactly what you want:

```
int fourDigitYear = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.ToFourDigitYear(twoDigitYear)
```

That way you will correctly adhere to current regional settings as defined in Control Panel (or group policy):

[image: Regional settings]

Comment: Are there any regional differences that influence 2 to 4 digit year conversion?

Comment: Or System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture or CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture or CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture, etc.

Comment: I'm running into this on some current code. Using the Thai cultural settings means that a year of 2000, stored as 00, is being interpreted as 3100 in the Buddhist Era, or 3100-543=2557 in the system! Very confusing bug until you realize what's going on.

Comment: Plot Twist: If you do `.ToFourDigitYear("99")` then it returns "1999" but if you do `.ToFourDigitYear("16")` it gives you 2016. Looks like 0-29 will give you in the 2000s and anything over that will give you in the 1900s.

Comment: @Sinaesthetic There's no plot twist; it's working as defined in the regional settings.

Comment: work on my system, with PersianCalendar, doesn't work on one of servers with same calendar

Comment: @deadManN check what calendar is set for the user under which application is running on the server.

Comment: it wasn't my project, and he got it done. btw, thanks for the reply

Comment: If I do this with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, will the range be fixed to 1930-2029 forever or is it somehow adjusted over time?

Answer (score 16):

Given that there are people alive now born before 1950, but none born after 2010, your use of 50 as the flipping point seems broken.

For date of birth, can you not set the flip point to the 'year of now' (i.e. 10) in your app?  Even then you'll have problems with those born before 1911...

There's no perfect way to do this - you're creating information out of thin air.

I've assumed DOB = date-of-birth.  For other data (say, maturity of a financial instrument) the choice might be different, but just as imperfect.

Comment: You are right about the DOB, but they are for animals not humans, and their lifespan is at most 40 years. but you are right about using a moving target. I will now use `if (Convert.ToInt16(String.Format("20{0}", tmpYear[2])) > DateTime.Today.Year + 3) // Causes Y2.1K problem, but I will be retired by then.`

Comment: Like an animal _Logan's Run_ eh?  With a moving threshold year, and given no 100year+ lifespans, you should be ok.  I assumed humans obviously.  You could address the Y2K1 issue by making the Century part derive from Today too...

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the DateTime.TryParse method to convert your date. It uses the current culture settings to define the pivot year (in my case it is 2029)

```
DateTime resultDate;
Console.WriteLine("CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax : {0}", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax);
DateTime.TryParse("01/01/28", out resultDate);
Console.WriteLine("Generated date with year=28 - {0}",resultDate);
DateTime.TryParse("01/02/29",out resultDate);
Console.WriteLine("Generated date with year=29 - {0}", resultDate);
DateTime.TryParse("01/03/30", out resultDate);
Console.WriteLine("Generated date with year=30 - {0}", resultDate);
```

The output is:

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax : 2029

Generated date with year=28 - 01/01/2028 00:00:00

Generated date with year=29 - 01/02/2029 00:00:00

Generated date with year=30 - 01/03/1930 00:00:00

If you want to change the behavior you can create a culture with the year you want to use as pivot. This thread shows an example

[DateTime.TryParse century control C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277320/datetime-string-parsing/1277357#1277357)

But as martin stated, if you want to manage a time period that spans more than 100 year, there is no way to do it with only 2 digits.

Comment: FYI the TwoDigitYearMax is set in the control panel. Under Regional and Language options.

Answer (score 5):

I think Java has a good implementation of this:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#year

People rarely specify years far into the future using a two-digit code. The Java implementation handles this by assuming a range of 80 years behind and 20 years ahead of the current year. So right now, 30 would be 2030, while 31 would be 1931. Additionally, this implementation is flexible, modifying its ranges as time goes on, so that you don't have to change the code every decade or so.

I just tested, and Excel also uses these same rules for 2-digit year conversion. 1/1/29 turns into 1/1/2029. 1/1/30 turns into 1/1/1930.

Comment: JFYI, six years later, Excel and Google spreadsheets are still using 30 as the watershed year, so while Java may have a floating window, Excel and GS might not be quite as smart.

Comment: @ChrisB well, the original implementation of Excel wasn't quite that smart, now they're both sticking with those rules for compatibility reasons :)

Answer (score 5):

The implementation of

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.ToFourDigitYear
```

is

```
public virtual int ToFourDigitYear(int year)
{
  if (year < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("year", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));
  if (year < 100)
    return (this.TwoDigitYearMax / 100 - (year > this.TwoDigitYearMax % 100 ? 1 : 0)) * 100 + year;
  else
    return year;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You should also show how TwoDigitYearMax is filled in while you're at it.

Answer (score 4):

It might be smarter to check tmpYear > currentYear%100. If it is, then it's 19XX, otherwise 20XX.

Answer (score 2):

This Method can convert the credit card last two year digits to four year

---

```
private static int ToFourDigitYear(int year)
{
    string stringYear = year.ToString("00");
    if (stringYear.Length == 2)
    {
        int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
        string firstTwoDigitsOfCurrentYear = currentYear.ToString().Substring(0, 2);
        year = Convert.ToInt32(firstTwoDigitsOfCurrentYear + stringYear);
        if (year < currentYear)
            year = year + 100;
    }
    return year;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged, as they don't provide any insight on how to solve the problem at hand. Please update your solution to explain how your code solves the OP's problem :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution we use for Expiration Dates, the user enters MM and YY into separate fields. This results in dates being the 31st or 30th and 28th or 29th also for February.

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates datetime for current century and sets days to end of month
/// </summary>
/// <param name="MM"></param>
/// <param name="YY"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static DateTime GetEndOfMonth(string MM, string YY)
{
    // YY -> YYYY #RipVanWinkle
    // Gets Current century and adds YY to it.
    // Minus 5 to allow dates that may be expired to be entered.
    // eg. today is 2017, 12 = 2012 and 11 = 2111
    int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    string thisYear = currentYear.ToString().Substring(0, 2) + YY;
    int month = Int32.Parse(MM);
    int year = Int32.Parse(thisYear);
    if ((currentYear - 5) > year)
        year += 100;

    return new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer will not match your question but for credit cards I just add 2 digits of current year

```
private int UpconvertTwoDigitYearToFour(int yearTwoOrFour)
{
    try
    {
        if (yearTwoOrFour.ToString().Length <= 2)
        {
            DateTime yearOnly = DateTime.ParseExact(yearTwoOrFour.ToString("D2"), "yy", null);
            return yearOnly.Year;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return yearTwoOrFour;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, from where do you get this data? From a form? In that case; I would simply ask the user to fill in (or somehow select) the year with four digits or get the users age and month/day of birth, and use that data to figure out what year they were born. That way, you wouldn't have to worry about this problem at all :)

**Edit:** Use [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) for working with this kind of data.

Comment: If you ask a dog for the year it was born, you don't want to wait until it barks all the way up to 2003! 
3 quick yaps is more efficient...

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code

//Invoke TextBoxDateFormat method with date as parameter.

Method

```
public void TextBoxDateFormat(string str1)

{

// Takes the current date format if MM/DD/YY or MM/DD/YYYY

DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(str1);

//Converts the requested date into MM/DD/YYYY and assign it to textbox field

TextBox = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt.ToShortDateString());


//include your validation code if required

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, and came up with this... HTH!

```
value = this.GetDate()

if (value.Length >= 6)//ensure that the date is mmddyy
{
    int year = 0;

    if (int.TryParse(value.Substring(4, 2), out year))
    {
        int pastMillenium = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy").Substring(0, 2)) - 1;

        if (year > int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yy")))//if its a future year it's most likely 19XX
        {
            value = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", value.Substring(0, 4), pastMillenium, year.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
        }
        else
        {
            value = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", value.Substring(0, 4), pastMillenium + 1, year.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        value = string.Empty;
    }
}
else
{
    value = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer will not match your question but for credit cards I just add 2 digits of current year

```
    private int UpconvertTwoDigitYearToFour(int yearTwoOrFour)
    {
        try
        {
            if (yearTwoOrFour.ToString().Length <= 2)
            {
                DateTime yearOnly = DateTime.ParseExact(yearTwoOrFour.ToString("D2"), "yy", null);
                return yearOnly.Year;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return yearTwoOrFour;
    }
```

Comment: Exception: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate for a person he will probably not be more than 100 years...

Eg: 751212

```
var nr = "751212";
var century = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-100).Year.ToString().Substring(0, 2);

var days = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(century + nr)).Days;
decimal years = days / 365.25m;
if(years>=99)
 century = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().Substring(0, 2);

var fullnr = century+nr;
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a 2-digit year to 4-digit current or earlier -

```
year = year + (DateTime.Today.Year - DateTime.Today.Year%100);
if (year > DateTime.Today.Year)
                year = year - 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents,

Given an age range=[18, 100+], two digits year=90, I can do

`current year - twoDigitsYear` = `2018 - 90 = 1928`, I got 19, 28

hence 19 is the first two digits of year of born, and 28 is the age, which is
year=1990, age=28

But it won't work when age 0 and 100 both included in the range, same to some of the other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on above solutions, here is mine, i used in android while using java

> it takes current year in two digit format then checks for if input
>   year length is equal to 2, if yes then it get current year and from
>   this year it splits first two digits of century, then it adds this
>   century with year user input. to make it 4 digit year.

```
public static int getConvertedYearFromTwoToFourDigits(String year) {
        if (year.length() == 2) {
            int currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
            String firstTwoDigitsOfCurrentYear = String.valueOf(currentYear).substring(0, 2);
            year = firstTwoDigitsOfCurrentYear + year;
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(year);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int fYear = Convert.ToInt32(txtYear.Value.ToString().Substring(2, 2));
```