# 2 Digit Year Index Number to 4 Digit Year Index Number without Regex

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to replace an ugly method in an application.  The purpose is to convert a 2 Digit Year Legal Index Number to 4 Digit Year Legal Index Number.
Is there a way to do this without using Regular Expressions

So:

> 12345/15 => 12345/2015
>
> 67831/12 => 67831/2012
>
> *etc*

The following Method works but is bulky and doesn't seem very bulletproof to me.

```
public static string IndexNumber2YrTo4Yr(string inp)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"\/\d{0,2}$");
    var match = regex.Match(inp);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var twoDigitYear = inp.Substring(inp.Length - 2);
        try
        {
            var twoDigitInt = Convert.ToInt32(twoDigitYear);
            var fourDigitYear = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
                                .Calendar.ToFourDigitYear(twoDigitInt).ToString();
            return inp.Replace(@"/" + twoDigitYear, @"/" + fourDigitYear);
        }
        catch { return inp; }
    }
    return inp;
}
```

Does anyone know a more elegant way to accomplish this without using regex.

Comment: Do you definitely want to use the current culture's calendar for the decision about what the two digit year means? Do you not have your own specific rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).

Code snippet:

```
const char delimiter = '/';
string[] split = inp.Split(delimiter);
int year = DateTime.ParseExact(split[1], "yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Year;
return split[0] + delimiter + year;
```

---

### Notes

1. Parsing two-digits year works as following:

> Converts the year value to the appropriate century by using the
>   TwoDigitYearMax property.  For example, if the TwoDigitYearMax value is 2029,
>   then a two digit value of 30 will get converted to 1930 while a two digit
>   value of 29 will get converted to 2029.

Please also note that `ParseExact` and `TryParseExact` invokes `parseInfo.calendar.ToFourDigitYear(result.Year)` underhood.

See also: 
[Convert a two digit year to a four digit year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024273/convert-a-two-digit-year-to-a-four-digit-year).

2. If DateTime parsing logic doesn't satisfy you, you may write simple if-statement on your own.
3. The code snippet doesn't include validation. In this case, I'd recommend using [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx), so you can validate whether the second part is a year or not.

Comment: That's assuming that "12345/99" should be "12345/2099" - I suspect it should actually be "12345/1999"

Comment: @JonSkeet: True. Fixed now :)

Comment: Also this throws if the value after the slash isn't numeric or there isn't a slash at all, where as the current code would return the original value.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is another issue.  Actually at this point most of the numbers are 2000 cases but you will have the odd ball cases that are 1900.  I don't think there is a way to account for it though tbh.  The data entry forces the user to enter xxxx/YYYY the problem is they like to search xxxx/YY resulting in no cases being returned.

Comment: @juharr: As per noted, I'm not adding validation to that code snippet.

Comment: @DariuszWoźniak This seems to be the lesser of two evils, thank you.  And as far as the validation it is not as much of a concern in this particular instance.  Thanks Dariusz !

Answer (score 1):

There is probably not a super clean way to do it, here is a way with `String.Split` and determining the century manually.

```
            var split = inp.Split('/');
            if(split.Length > 1)
            {
                 string yearString = split[1];
                 int yearInt = 0;
                 if(int.TryParse(yearString, out yearInt ))
                 {
                     if(yearInt > 50)
                        return split[0] + "19" + yearInt.ToString();
                     else
                        return split[0] + "20" + yearInt.ToString();

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     //handle error
                 }
            }
            else
            {
                //handle error
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it was my project (or apparently if I was answering a question on SO), I'd start with something like this:

Obviously I've made some assumptions about the actual format of the index.

```
    public static string IndexNumber2YrTo4Yr(string inp)
    {
        if (inp == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("inp");
        }

        string[] parts;

        parts = inp.Split('/');

        if (
            parts.Length != 2 ||
            parts[0].Length != 5 ||
            parts[1].Length != 2
        )
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Index number invalid", "inp");
        }

        int twoDigitYear = 0;

        try
        {
            twoDigitYear = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Year invalid", "inp", e);
        }

        return string.Format("{0}/{1:0000}", parts[0], YearTwoDigitToFourDigit(twoDigitYear));
    }

    public static int YearTwoDigitToFourDigit(int twoDigitYear)
    {
        if (twoDigitYear < 0 || twoDigitYear > 99)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("twoDigitYear");
        }

        // Do we like these rules? Or should we define them.
        return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.ToFourDigitYear(twoDigitYear);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can give a try is :
use DateTime.ParseExact() and provide a format like "mm/yy" or "dd/mm/yy" or similar formats, You might get what you expect.

Let's say if the the input is "09/41", you should expect September ,1941.

I guess it should help.

Comment: The part before the slash is clearly not part of a date.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Good Idea but it is not a date it is a legal identification number

Comment: I had situations where I got this kind of input,and had to convert it to DateTime.

Comment: @juharr , if you have things like "01/41", how are you going to interpret it to DateTime?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh  If the value was "01/41" and I knew it was a month/year then I would use `DateTime.ParseExact`, but that's not what the question is about.  The values the OP is working with are not dates.  They just have year values at the end that the OP wants to convert from 2 digits to 4.

Comment: He, then has ran into situations we never did. Fare?

Comment: Well Andew Parode told me, CLR is intelligent enough, while people complain it is not.